# Connect to server on command line

Tags: macos, finder, command-line, nas, afp

I am currently trying to connect my NAS on OSX 10.9.5 using the command line. This will work fine if I first connect my NAS using Finder: I select it in the "Shared" section of Finder's sidebar, click "Connect" and it will connect using the credentials from the keychain and list all available shares.

Then I can use *mount_afp* on the command line to mount my shares. However, without performing this step in Finder, the following will occur:

```
$ mount_afp afp://MyNAS._afpovertcp._tcp.local/my_share /path/to/mount_point
mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error -5002, errno is -5002
```

How can I perform the "connect" operation from Finder on the command line?

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots or images to illustrate your steps? I might be able to help but it would be a lot easier if I could actually see what we're talking about.

Comment: Sure, the corresponding Finder view can be see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ME8Gj.png), original source: http://superuser.com/questions/283863/force-finder-to-log-in-as-guest-to-a-smb-share